# How to find broken links on web application using UIPath?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I need to Automate my web application Using UIPATH. I need to find broken links on Web application using UIPATH RPA tool.

Comment: There are already plenty tools that can do that. Do not reinvent what already exists. Or what do you need it for?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

UiPath bots are not best tool for this problem, search the web for alternative and better tools.
I found this may be useful for you.

https://geekflare.com/find-broken-links-within-your-website/